# How to make Nodejs pickup changes rather than restarting the server every time?

Tags: node.js

Is there a way for Nodejs to reflect the changes done in my files, rather than closing the node and running it again?
I'm still in the development phase so I make a lot of changes, so what I do is I stop the server each time and run it again (with "node" command)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use nodemon to monitor your files and will restart automatically when there is any changes:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

after you can still use your command `npm start` but you will have to replace this line in package.json

```
"scripts":{
  // "start": "node ./bin/www"
  "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
}
```

Answer (score 30):

I prefer to use https://github.com/remy/nodemon you can install it globally

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

and start your server by doing

```
nodemon app.js
```

Comment: I have installed nodemon. But running server using nodemon index.js is not doing anything. No error and nothing else. Server is not starting at all. Could you please let me know what is the issue behind it.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor):

> A little supervisor script for nodejs. It runs your program, and
>   watches for code changes, so you can have hot-code reloading-ish
>   behavior, without worrying about memory leaks and making sure you
>   clean up all the inter-module references, and without a whole new
>   require system.